# Spring: mapping string and numbers with RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following form in Spring:

```
<form:form method="post" action="addprice.html" commandName="addprice">
<form:input path="name" />
<form:input path="price" />
<input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="Add price"/>"/>    
</form:form>
```

And I need to pass the parameters to the following function:

```
@RequestMapping("/addprice")
public String addPrice( 
// WHAT I NEED TO WRITE HERE?
) 
{
    // function code
}
```

What I need to write between parentesys in the previous function in order to retrieve "name" and "price"?

I tried using @ModelAttribute but it seems to work only with entities and I don't have a unique entity in this case but just two simple parameters.

Comment: You can use `@RequestParam` in the argument list to have Spring map the request parameter to an Object. IF however you have an Command object that has fields that are named `name` and `price`, you can just  declare a parameter of your type.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@RequestParam` annotation :

```
@RequestMapping("/addprice")
public String addPrice(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam double price) 
{
    // function code
}
```